# How to format Alfresco'API parameter activityFilter in servce user activities feed ?

Tags: alfresco

I need to use that api : http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Freferences%2FRESTful-FeedUserfeedGet.html

What I don't know is how to format activityFilter parameter ? What kind of things can I filter ? I'd like to set a max number of results, is it possible ?

I don't know where to find the documentation.

Thank you.

Mathieu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where/if the list is documented, but it isn't hard to find out the values you are looking for...

The first place to go is the Web Script Index, which is:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index
```

From there you can find that web script, click on its ID, and see its declaration, any accompanying documentation, and, often, the code of the web script controller.

In this case, the controller is Java-based, so you can get its class and go look at that in the source.

Often, that's not convenient. So the next thing to do is to realize that Alfresco Share makes use of the same web script. If you turn on Firebug and go to the Alfresco Share Global Dashboard you can see the activity feed dashlet. As you change the second dropdown (the one that defaults to "all items") you will see your browser doing GETs against that web script. By choosing the various choices available in the dashlet, you'll see that the values it uses to filter activities are:

```
org.alfresco.comments.comment-created
org.alfresco.comments.comment-updated
org.alfresco.documentlibrary.file-added
org.alfresco.documentlibrary.file-deleted
org.alfresco.documentlibrary.file-updated
org.alfresco.documentlibrary.files-added
org.alfresco.documentlibrary.files-deleted
org.alfresco.documentlibrary.files-updated
org.alfresco.profile.status-changed
org.alfresco.site.user-joined
org.alfresco.site.user-left
org.alfresco.site.user-role-changed
```

You can pass more than one of these at-a-time to the web script by separating each with an escaped comma (%2C).

There may be more filters available, but those are the ones used by the activity feed dashlet on the global dashboard.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, didn't realize there was an alfresco actities feed dashlet. I thought there was only a share one. So now yeah, it's easy to find what I want. Thank you.